# How can I make my Garlic Bread less soggy?

Tags: bread

I want to make simple garlic bread pieces without getting them too soggy in the middle due to butter. Most of the restaurants near my area get this wrong - the bread pieces are soggy and yellow due to the butter they use and crunchy and tough on the crust. I want to try and making garlic bread but I want to avoid getting them soggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restaurants are making garlic bread quickly and in bulk, that can effect their processes, and results.  They are usually content to smear the garlic butter quickly, and mostly over the center, because it quickly covers most of the bread.  It is forgiving enough, and spreads enough, that the garlic bread they make this way is still pretty good - but being a little more careful might be all you need to make it better for your tastes.

If you're worried about sogginess, use a thin layer of garlic butter to start with, and spread it evenly towards the edges of your bread.  If you really want to be careful, scrape the garlic butter back off the very center of your bread.  This way, you won't have an extra puddle of butter in the center, and your edges won't get hard and dry from having less.

Additionally, make sure your garlic bread is toasted fairly quickly and at a high enough temperature.  If it is toasted at a much lower temperature or sits for a longer time afterwards, it is more likely to melt and puddle and soak the butter into the bread before it finishes toasting.  All you really should need for your garlic bread is to warm the bread and toast the top a little.  This can be done quickly, and the bread toasted and eaten while still warm and fresh, so it doesn't have time to get soggy.

If you're really wanting a drier garlic bread, you might consider lightly toasting the bread before you put the garlic butter on - and toasting again (or not) afterwards at your preference.  This will draw some of the moisture out from the bread, and form a drier crust between the bread and butter, which should help keep it from getting too soggy.

Answer (score 2):

Easy -- don't use butter.

Put the sliced bread in the oven 'til it's toasted, then remove, and take a garlic clove and rub it over the sliced & toasted side.

The texture of the toasted bread should act like sandpaper, and slowly grate off bits of the garlic clove.  As you get to the end of the clove, you might need to abandon it and get another whole clove to use.

Another alternative is to roast your garlic, and then use it as a spread on the toasted bread.

Answer (score 2):

Toast your bread in the oven under a broiler first to the desired color, then when you pull it out of the oven, baste the bread with a baster and melted garlic butter.

I love crunchy garlic bread and this is how I achieve it.